# Spring Boot 2 & Spring 5 error serving index.html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a total simple Spring Boot app written in Kotlin.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication::class.java, *args)
}


@Controller
class HomeController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun home() = "index.html"
}
```

In the `resource/public` folder I have `index.html`.

However, when I open my browser and type`localhost:8080/` I get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'index.html'` in the running Spring Boot console.

I just want the most minimal code possbile to serve index.html. Shouldnt be that hard? ;)

**NOTE: I am using Spring-Web-Reactive**

Comment: Is it necessary to add that ``home()`` message? I think the index.html will be accessible even without it

Comment: First I doubt you need that method second if you return something it should be `index` which will be resolved by your view resolvers to a proper template.